# Show all authorizations by registers

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-4-2-1

I have this problem:

[image]

I have a controller:

```
  def index
    if params[:search_employee_by_cpf].present?
      @employees = Employee.search_cpf(params[:search_employee_by_cpf]).all
      @authorizations = Authorization.search_employee_by_cpf(params[:search_employee_by_cpf]).all
    end
  end
```

Model authorization:

```
  scope :search_employee_by_cpf, -> (cpf) { Authorization.joins("INNER JOIN employees ON employees.id = authorizations.employee_id INNER JOIN people ON employees.person_id = people.id").where("people.cpf LIKE ?", "%#{cpf}%") }
```

And model Employee:

```
  scope :search_cpf, -> (cpf) { joins(:person).where("people.cpf LIKE ?", "%#{cpf}%") }
```

I need two register/matricula and I need show authorizations for each register/matricula. Actually, show all authorization for each register and this is wrong! I just want show the authorizations of respective register. How make this?

**UPDATE -------------------------**

This is a part of my view responsable for show authorizations

```
<% @authorizations.each do |authorization| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= check_box_tag 'authorization[contract_ids][]', authorization.contract_number %></td>
              <td><%= authorization.contract_number %></td>
              <td><%= number_to_currency authorization.parcel_value %></td>
              <td><%= authorization.qtd_parcel %></td>
              <td><%= number_to_currency authorization.total_value %></td>
              <td>
                <%= simple_form_for('/', remote: true) do |f| %>
                  <%= f.input :value_solve, label: false, placeholder: "Digit a value" %>
                  <%= f.submit 'Gravar valor' %>
                <% end %>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
```

**UPDATE 2 -------------------------**

```
  def new
    if params[:authorization]
      @selected_ids = params[:authorization][:contract_ids]
      @authorizations = Authorization.where("contract_number in (?)", @selected_ids)
    end
    @employee = Employee.search_cpf(params[:search_employee_by_cpf])
    @refinancing = Refinancing.new
  end
```

new.html.erb (after checked and click on button go to new)

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><%= @employee.person.name %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CPF:</td>
    <td><%= @employee.person.cpf %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you also post your view file and model relationships here?

Comment: is cpf just a column of people table?

Comment: can you post your schema here? the model relationship is hard to guess

Comment: cpf is just a column people table

Comment: I just want .where something instead of .all

Comment: @ZhiliangTakutoXing I make better, take a look this example on git: https://github.com/eltonsantos/playing_checkboxes

Comment: unless i understand your intention wrong, for example one `employee` can have many `people`, otherwise you don't need the scope method in `Authorization` because unless one employee can have different people, their authorizations will all have the same `cpf`, therefore it's useless to filter authorizations using `cpf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after I look at you database tables, I have a question. It appears that one `employee` can have only one `person` which contains `cpf`, in that case I don't think the scope method in `Authorization` is necessary anymore. Because obviously each `employee`'s authorizations will all have only one `cpf`. you can simply just do

```
@employees = Employee.search_cpf(params[:search_employee_by_cpf]).includes(:authorizations)
```

in your view, change

```
<% @authorizations.each do |authorization| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag 'authorization[contract_ids][]', authorization.contract_number %></td>
    <td><%= authorization.contract_number %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency authorization.parcel_value %></td>
    <td><%= authorization.qtd_parcel %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency authorization.total_value %></td>
    <td>
      <%= simple_form_for('/', remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :value_solve, label: false, placeholder: "Digit a value" %>
        <%= f.submit 'Gravar valor' %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<% employee.authorizations.each do |authorization| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag 'authorization[contract_ids][]', authorization.contract_number %></td>
    <td><%= authorization.contract_number %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency authorization.parcel_value %></td>
    <td><%= authorization.qtd_parcel %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency authorization.total_value %></td>
    <td>
      <%= simple_form_for('/', remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :value_solve, label: false, placeholder: "Digit a value" %>
        <%= f.submit 'Gravar valor' %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Get a error, I make equal you did... Association named 'authorizations' was not found on Employee; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: in your `Employee` model, add `has_many :authorizations`, you have `belongs_to :employee` in you `Authorization` model. I think you missed it

Comment: Yes, employee can have only one person which contains cpf. Authorization belongs to employee and employee has many refinancings... A employee has many register (but register is only a column)

Comment: Dammm, when I click on button bronken next view ... undefined method `person' for #<Employee::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe4a2f323c8>

Comment: how come, I think you have `belongs_to :person` in `Employee` model

Comment: wait, it is `<Employee::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe4a2f323c8>`? then it is wrong, this is a collection like an array,  you cannot call `person` on it

Comment: the solution that i think is put @employee.first.person.name... but it too is wrong

Comment: Hey <%= @employee.first.person.name %> solve my problem, but I can do it?

Comment: The method is new and is here: https://github.com/eltonsantos/playing_checkboxes/blob/master/app/controllers/refinancings_controller.rb - @employee is the same employee of before view.

Comment: it is not ok unfortunately , coz from your graph, cpf is not unique in `Person` Model.

Comment: try to describe your logic in `new` action, which employee you want to query? if you only search by using cpf, in the case you show in the first graph, you will find two employees, not one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108990/discussion-between-zhiliang-takuto-xing-and-elton-santos).